# Select all innerHTML of td in ul li hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an html structure as follows-

```
<ul id='abc'>
    <li>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        A
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </li>
    <li>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        B
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </li>       
    ...
    ...
</ul>
```

I want to store A,B,C... values in an array using jquery.Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by javascript by The

> [`Element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) method returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name

```
var values = []
var tableUl = document.getElementById("abc"); 
var cells = tableUl.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { 
    values.push( cells[i].textContent.trim()); 

}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjofuaod/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`$.fn.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

> Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

```
var arr = $('#abc td').map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Comment: @lucasnadalutti, no here I have used [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

Comment: thanks , i Embarrassed myself  enough in that answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you want:

```
var values = [];
$('ul li').find('td').each(function() {
  values.push($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`var values = $('ul#abc td').map(function() { return $(this).text(); });`

Comment: edited.. now it's storing them.. how are you interpretting my answer as a critique..?  storing the result of an expression in js is trivia I assumed it wasn't the point of the question..  also my answer is nearly identical to many others why am I being criticized?

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.text()` , `String.prototype.match()`

```js
var res = $("#abc td").text().match(/\w+/gi)

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul id='abc'>
    <li>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        A
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </li>
    <li>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        B
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </li>       
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be:

```
$("ul#abc li td:first-child").each(function () {
   //alert($(this).text());
   console.log($(this).text());
 });
```